# How to make api calls using react/redux and jsonp using redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsonp, redux-saga

I'm building a simple react/redux app that makes a request to the [giantbomb api](https://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation) using jsonp. I'm using redux-saga to handle the api call along with [jsonp-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp-promise). I make the call in the saga, which returns a promise, but that promise simply times out before I can dispatch the action and response data to the reducer. There's also the global callback function, which appears to receive the response data but I don't know where it would go in the flow of the saga, or if I even need to use it at all.

```
import { takeEvery, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import jsonp from 'jsonp-promise';

let setVideoCallback = "cb" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
window[setVideoCallback] = function(response) {
  console.log(response);
} 


// workers
export function* setVideoAsync() {
  try {
    console.log('attempting to set video via api call');
    let jsonpArgs = [
      "https://www.giantbomb.com/api/videos/" +
      "?api_key=816627d452ffb34d20762fd2f3b575dfe906bfd9" +
      "&format=jsonp&json_callback=" +
      setVideoCallback +
      "&limit=1&field_list=hd_url,name,deck,publish_date," +
      "user&filter=video_type:3,video_type8" +
      "&sort=publish_date:desc",
      {param: 'json_callback'}
    ];

    let response = yield call(jsonp, jsonpArgs);
    const promise = response.promise;
    console.log('promise in worker saga:');
    console.log(promise);
    response = yield promise;
    yield put({type: 'VIDEO_SET_SUCCEEDED', response: response.data 
});
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('setVideoAsync request failed!');
    console.log(e);

    yield put({type: 'VIDEO_SET_FAILED', message: e.message });
  }
}

// watchers
export function* watchSetVideo() {
  console.log('redux-saga is running the VIDEO_SET action listener');
  yield takeEvery('VIDEO_SET', setVideoAsync);
}
```

How do I get the promise to resolve? Or otherwise correctly make the api call?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Looks like the function in `call` needs to return a promise for redux-saga to suspend the generator and resolve it. so I simply wrapped `jsonp` in another function that returns its promise attribute and used that function as call's first argument instead.